# Bad spacing when executing two user defined commands side by side

Tags: horizontal-alignment

Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

To this purpose I've written the following commands:

```tex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}

\setdefaultlanguage[variant=us]{english}

\setmainfont{CMU Concrete}
\setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif}
\setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}

\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\definecolor{keywdcolor}{HTML}{bf616a}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\keywd}{m}{
    \ttfamily\bfseries
    \textcolor{keywdcolor}{#1}
}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\apicmd}{m}{
    \keywd{\textbackslash#1\xspace}
}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\apienv}{m}{
    \keywd{\{#1\}\xspace}
}

\definecolor{argscolor}{HTML}{a3be8c}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\argcontent}{m}{
    \ttfamily\bfseries
    \textcolor{argscolor}{\xspace\ensuremath{\langle}\textit{#1}\ensuremath{\rangle}\xspace}
}
```

but when I try to implement it like this:

```tex
\begin{document}
   \apicmd{path}\apiopt{shape}
\end{document}
```

this is the result:

[image]

Any idea why this happens and how I could correct it?

Comment: You have many unprotected endlines. See [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines? (Why is my macro creating extra space?)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453) Also `\xspace` does nothing at all in those cases.

Comment: Problem solved! Thank you very much @egreg. And everything in less tha 4 min.s. I'm impressed.

Comment: unrelated but are you _sure_ you want `luainputenc` (it has its uses but it is a tricky thing and disables most of luatex font support)

Comment: No I'm NOT. I admit I just pasted and copied a LyX export output. I didn't know --- and clearly I still don' t --- what to write in the preamble to ensure that I'm using LuaTeX.
So you would leave it out, wouldn't you?